# Azure Data Warehouse Error while inserting GETDATE() to a datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I am trying to insert current date into a `datetime` column in Azure SQL Data Warehouse but getting the following error.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (MYTEXT VARCHAR(15), MYDATE DATETIME); 

INSERT INTO TEST (MYTEXT, MYDATE) 
VALUES ('ABCD', GETDATE());
```

> Msg 104334, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Insert values statement can contain only constant literal values or variable references.

Comment: Well, `GETDATE()` is neither a constant literal value nor a variable reference. Use `INSERT .. SELECT` instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate? The same statement works in SQL Server.

Comment: @user2263025, it works now, but in a past similar error would be triggered also by SQL Server. Perhaps ADW has stricter requirements of `INSERT INTO` than a regular data engine

Comment: And Azure SQL Data Warehouse is not SQL Server. Same product family, not quite the same implementation. Indeed, that specific error message is nowhere to be found in `sys.messages` of SQL Server 2017. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql) could stand to do with mentioning this (they only mention a different syntax, but that syntax mentions `expression`, with no restriction on the expression types).

Comment: So, how do you insert the current date into a datetime column in ADW?

Comment: You're telling me `INSERT TEST(MYTEXT, MYDATE) SELECT 'ABCD', GETDATE()` doesn't work? Because that *would* surprise me.

Answer (score 5):

> Msg 104334, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Insert values statement can contain only **constant literal** values or **variable** references.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
SET @Date = GETDATE();

INSERT INTO TEST (MYTEXT, MYDATE) 
VALUES ('ABCD', @Date);
```

The first value is a constant literal and the second is variable

Comment: Good enough. But I have a situation where I want Azure Stream Analytics to write into this database. Meaning, I do not have the privilege of defining variables etc. Need a straight SQL to insert this value :-)

Comment: Then create a default value for that column and omit it in INSERT - DEFAULT (GETDATE())

Comment: That's a challenge again.

Msg 104338, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
An expression cannot be used with a default constraint. Specify only constants for a default constraint

Comment: Then perhaps advice of Jeroen  is a way to go: insert.. select

Comment: So the real question is: How do insert a timestamp into SQL DW from Azure Stream Analytics? This is a loong way from your original question. Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/stream-analytics-query/system-timestamp-stream-analytics

Answer (score 1):

On Azure Synapse (formally known as Azure Data Warehouse) insert values can only be constant literal or variable references. You can set the value to a variable or simpler:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TEST (MYTEXT VARCHAR(15), MYDATE DATETIME); 

INSERT INTO TEST (MYTEXT, MYDATE) 
SELECT 'ABCD', GETDATE() AS DATETIME;
```